# Nodejs mongoose: how can I find a subset of all documents?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection in mongodb that has more than 100000 documents. Each time I apply `Model.find()`, it returns all documents in an array.

But for some reasons like unnecessary data or performance, speed of the query, I just want to find document that is:

- Starting with first document
- The second document will be the 300th document
- The third document will be the 600th document
- ...
- The final document will be the 100000th document

Is there any mongoose query for that?

Comment: You want to find by _id or Date?

Comment: Have you looked into using [Query.skip](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) and [Query.limit](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit)? Or are you specifically looking get every document with an index divisible by 300?